# Android Volley and IntentService / AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to refactor my app using Volley as HTTP library.
The current architecture includes using IntentService and AsyncTaskLoader for handling REST requests, and both of them start a new background thread.

Is it possibile to keep the current architecture and use Volley in conjunction with IntentService and AsyncTaskLoader? 
I presume that to do this I should use Volley starting synchronous requests inside IntentService or AsyncTaskLoader, but looking at documentation and examples this doesn't look like the standard way to use Volley and maybe it would also decrease the performance benefits of the library itself.

Does introducing Volley mean getting rid of Services in our Android apps architecture?

Comment: some code would definitely not harm